# alias кириллицей с пробелами в запросе firebird sql

Tags: sql, firebird

Как правильно задать alias Русскими буквами с пробелами.

Например:

```
select name as "Имя пользователя" from users;
```

В **firebird** выдает ошибку "SQL error code = -104"

Проходят только следующие запросы

```
select name as User_name from users;
select name User_name from users;
```

С кириллицей, что с пробелом, что без него не получается.

Может кто сталкивался с данной ситуацией?

*Существует ли способ это обойти путем конвертации алиаса или преобразования в hex или char?*

Следующие запросы не работают даже англ. буквами.:

```
select name as "User name" from users;
select name as 'User name' from users;
select name as {User name} from users;
select name as [User name] from users;
```

Версия бд: **Firebird 2.5**

Comment: Документацию читать не пробовали? Попробуйте: https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-structure-identifiers.html особенно обращая внимание на то, какие символы допускаются.

Comment: Немного поправил вопрос.

Comment: Вот вроде вменяемо и вполне однозначно пишут: *It may contain characters from **any Latin character set**, including a accented characters, spaces and special characters*. Причём разработчики пишут, не кто-то там. И всё равно "как обойти"... да и на то, что *Delimited identifiers are available in Dialect 3 only* тоже ноль внимания...

Comment: Спасибо. Очень жаль что нет возможности использования пробелов .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebird вроде как не принимает ни пробелы ни кириллицу. Даже в алиасах. Юзай подчеркивание